# Removing options from select with regex in jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I am using following selector to remove single item in select.

```
jQuery("#stateCity  option[value='Adak, AK, USA']").remove();
```

I want a selector that can remove all cities of a state. Like `*, AK, USA` will remove all cities of Alaska in the combo.

So what regex I should use to do it in one line? Of if I have to loop it. How can I do that.

```
<select name="stateCity" id="stateCity">
    <option value="Adak, AK, USA">Adak, AK, USA</option>
    <option value="Akhiok, AK, USA">Akhiok, AK, USA</option>
    <option value="Redwood, CA, USA">Redwood, CA, USA</option>
    <option value="AL, USA">AL, USA</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `jQuery("#stateCity  option[value$='AK, USA']").remove();`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8cuYM/

`$=` selects any element that the value ends with that you specified, in this case `AK, USA`.

Read more at http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/